# classes.dex file does't contain my java classes

Tags: java, android, jar, reverse-engineering, decompiling

[image]

I have developed an app in android studio and test it in my phone. I have formatted my computer and forgot to save my project to somewhere. Now i want to get my source codes back. I get the APK file from my phone (either by using adb and some other tools).

I am using dex2jar and decompile my classes.dex file but it does not show my own Java classes. Is it possible to get them back?

Comment: Even if you got your classses and decompiled them, they would be a mostly unreadable, and definitely unmaintainable mess.

Comment: why do you need that.? dex files are dalvik files ONLY required by the Dalvik or JVM

Comment: The only thing I want is to get back my classes which I have written in the project. I dont want to write them again. I only have my own application in my phone and I can pul the apk file. I just need to obtain my classes from this apk file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decompile it so easily a great tutorial below:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-decompile-an-android-app-apk

4 easy steps as below:

1- unzip you apk like you unzip any zip file

2-find classes.dex files

3-convert them to jar file using [dexToJar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) tool

4- open the jar file using [JD-Gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) application (availbale for windows/ubuntu/mac)

Comment: I did excatly what u sad step by step. However, in JD-Gui there are just a few classes which are not mine

Comment: Did you progaurd your apk ? Before releasing ?

Comment: I have decompiled a project containing 50 000 lines of code using this tool. Its a pieace of cake. Upload what you get in jdgui in your question ;) ill help you

Comment: ok I will upload it at evening. I m now working. Thank u very much btw..

Comment: I have uploaded what I see in jdgui. There are 2 packages and some classes. Non of them belong to me. I can send you the apk file if u can help me.. Thank you very much

Comment: What is the link of your application in google store ? Im eager to test it.

Comment: i didn't put it in google strore. As I sad it s my own application and i have tested it just on my phone. I can share you with google drive or dropbox somethng else

Comment: Can you send me the apk ? Ill test for you .

Comment: thank u very much. I ll appreciate it. I can email it to you. Can you send me an emoty email pls. This is my email   ibrahimsalgin@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done by some obfuscator, such as [Proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html). This means, among other things, that the class names of your classes will be changed into meaningless names (such as A/B/C) the names will still be different in the fully qualified path of a java class, e.g. you might have multiple ""A" classes in different packages, but other than that you will have those class names multiple times. In most cases it will not harm te functionality of your program, but it will make it harder to reverse-engineer.

If this is your app and you can rebuild it, you can disable ProGuard or a subset of its features, otherwise you will need to reverse engineer it on your own.